# How can I retrieve MySQL results into a dictionary that can be searched by index? (in Python)

Tags: python, mysql

I am learning Python programming to build some automations, part of the script I am building iterates over object, I want to be able to search for the same items within a MySQL DB but not quite sure how to do so.

Using the [MariaDB tutorial](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/how-to-connect-python-programs-to-mariadb/) I have successfully retrieved the rows I want, however I'm not sure how I can search for an item within the `cursor` list without having to manually iterate through each result.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

    # here I get a list of items from an external service
    playlists = sp.user_playlists(username)
    # here I retrieve my playlists from a DB
    cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, monitor FROM playlists")
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    while playlists:
        for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
            print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['id'],  playlist['name']))
            # while iterating through the playlists from the external service, I want to see if its included within my "rows" dictionary.

            key = "1"
            for row in rows:
                print("ID: {}, Name: {}, Monitor: {}".format(row['id'],row['name'], row['monitor']))

                # this does not work, there is an ID
                if key in rows:
                    print("found key")
                    break
                else:
                    print("NOT found key")


        if playlists['next']:
            playlists = sp.next(playlists)
        else:
            playlists = None
```

I have made comments around the area that I need some assistance from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few comments. In your code you set `key` to a constant `"1"`, which never varies, and that can't be right. `rows`, which is returned from the query, will be a list dictionaries. The statement `if key in rows:` is checking a key value not against the keys for each dictionary but rather against each row, which is an entire dictionary, and that is not right. This should be `if key == row['id']:`. So a couple of changes should help:

```
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

# here I get a list of items from an external service
playlists = sp.user_playlists(username)
# here I retrieve my playlists from a DB
cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, monitor FROM playlists")
rows = cursor.fetchall()
# build a dictionary of keys:
id_dict = {row['id']: row for row in rows}
while playlists:
    for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
        print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['id'],  playlist['name']))
        # while iterating through the playlists from the external service, I want to see if its included within my "rows" dictionary.

        key = playlist['id'] # the key
        if key in id_dict:
            row = id_dict[key]
            print("ID: {}, Name: {}, Monitor: {}".format(row['id'],row['name'], row['monitor']))
            print("found key")
        else:
            print("NOT found key")

    if playlists['next']:
        playlists = sp.next(playlists)
    else:
        playlists = None
```

**Another, More Efficient Way**

Don't query all the playlists from the database initially:

```
cursor = mariadb_connection.cursor(dictionary=True)

# here I get a list of items from an external service
playlists = sp.user_playlists(username)
# here I retrieve my playlists from a DB
while playlists:
    for i, playlist in enumerate(playlists['items']):
        print("%4d %s %s" % (i + 1 + playlists['offset'], playlist['id'],  playlist['name']))
        # while iterating through the playlists from the external service, I want to see if its included within my "rows" dictionary.
        id = playlist['id']
        cursor.execute("SELECT id, name, monitor FROM playlists where id = %s", (id,))
        row = cursor.fetchone() # this the match, if any
        if row:
            print("ID: {}, Name: {}, Monitor: {}".format(row['id'],row['name'], row['monitor']))
            print("found key")
        else:
            print("NOT found key")

    if playlists['next']:
        playlists = sp.next(playlists)
    else:
        playlists = None
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response, the manual set to `1` was just to debug it. I have switched to `playlist['id']` and this has still not worked. This is the bit I am unsure of, I dont think using `if key in rows` is searching through the keys, I cant actually verify which column its searching against or whether `rows` has a index set to the `id` column.

Comment: Secondly, why would you query the playlist id in the iterator? Isn't this inefficient? As you will likely be querying the database multiple times instead of just once?

Comment: What I was hoping for was a function that would allow me to search for keys within the `rows` dictionary. That way I wouldn't need to even do the second iteration, the inner condition statement or a query within the for loop.

Comment: Did not see this, I have changed the code so that its `if key in row:` this still doesn't find a match. Please see my third comment, if this is possible we wouldn't even need to iterate over all records.

Comment: Second, your original code could be, for all I know, reading in millions of rows depending on the size of the database and you are looping through the entire database. The more efficient code is just attempting to read a single row each time and if you have an index on `id`, which would surely be the case if it is a primary key, this would be more efficient.

Comment: Siily me (I had a case of brain fog). It should be `if key == row['id']:`.  I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks Booboo, this _does_ work but I was hoping _not_ to do this. I don't want to iterate over each result to find a match, but rather just check to see if this key exists in the collection (as described in my original question) as this will be far more efficient.

Comment: I've updated the answer to initially create a dictionary where the keys are the id's of the row and the values are the rows themselves

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.